# Mail Queue in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, email

I want to send bulk emails for users with different reminders for each user... If i send them one by one it will take a lot of time ... so is there any concept in asp.net which use a queue to do this and send mails from there.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending the same email to many users, send a single message with many addresses in the BCC field. The SMTP server will take care of breaking the message out for each destination. This way, your program only sends the message once, rather than sending the same message multiple times.